# AppBarLayout cannot be cast to androidx.appcompat.widget.Toolbar

Tags: android, xml, material-design

My app is crashing at start and that's the error i get
com.google.android.material.appbar.AppBarLayout cannot be cast to androidx.appcompat.widget.Toolbar

that's my XML file

```
<LinearLayout
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
tools:context=".MainActivity"
android:orientation="vertical">

<com.google.android.material.appbar.AppBarLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/mToolBar">
    <androidx.appcompat.widget.Toolbar
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">
        <ImageView
            android:layout_width="50dp"
            android:layout_height="50dp"
            android:src="@drawable/logo"/>

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/profileText"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"

            android:text="  Hello"
            android:textColor="#000"
            android:textSize="24sp"
            android:textStyle="italic|bold" />
    </androidx.appcompat.widget.Toolbar>

    <com.google.android.material.tabs.TabLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:id="@+id/tabLayout"
        app:tabTextColor="#000"
        app:tabSelectedTextColor="#fff"/>
</com.google.android.material.appbar.AppBarLayout>

<androidx.viewpager.widget.ViewPager
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:id="@+id/viewPager"/>
```

and i'm directed to this line of code`mToolBar = findViewById(R.id.mToolBar);`

i tried to change **<androidx.appcompat.widget.Toolbar**
to **<android.widget.Toolbar**
and it did not work
idk what's the solution help me please

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to get a reference to your `Toolbar`, you need to move your `android:id="@+id/mToolBar"` to your `Toolbar` and remove it from your `AppBarLayout`.

```
<com.google.android.material.appbar.AppBarLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">
    <androidx.appcompat.widget.Toolbar
        android:id="@+id/mToolBar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">
```

Comment: In kotlin when I try to (getActivity() as AppCompatActivity?)!!.setSupportActionBar inside a fragment passing the inflated toolbar as parameter for the setSupportActionBar it crashes and the error message is "AppBarLayout cannot be cast to android.widget.Toolbar" any thoughts on how to solve this issue?